# MMSeqs taxonomy running for over a day

Tags: assembly, metagenome, taxonomy

I've been trying to run mmseqs2 on a few metagenomic assemblies and despite my best efforts in reading the wiki and playing with parameters, the process is taking over a day.

In their paper they claim to be 2 - 18x faster than CAT. I ran CAT on the same datasets and they took at most a few hours. So I can only assume that the long run time for mmseqs is down to user error (i.e. me).

I am currently running the commands (general format):

```
mmseqs createdb metagenome1_scaffolds.fasta metagenome1_query_DB
mmseqs taxonomy metagenome1_query_DB /home/mmseqs2/NR/NR metagenome1_mmseqs_taxonomy.txt metagenome1_temp --tax-lineage 1 --orf-filter 1 --threads 24
```

Could someone please let me know where I'm going wrong or what parameters I can tweak to get this running in the expected time frame?

Comment: Have you contacted the developers about this? Do any of [these issues](https://github.com/soedinglab/MMseqs2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+slow) match the problem you're having?

Comment: Hi there! I actually got in running in ~4 hours but then the results are split into 24 semi-corrupted files (I used 24 threads). I have since contacted the developers and will post a solution once I get a response and figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much googling about I realised that I was missing a step! Here are the commands I used to get it running:

```
mmseqs createdb metagenome1_scaffolds.fasta metagenome1_query_DB
mmseqs taxonomy metagenome1_query_DB /home/mmseqs2/NR/NR metagenome1_mmseqs_taxonomy.txt metagenome1_temp --tax-lineage 1 --orf-filter 1 --threads 24 --split-memory-limit 500G 
mmseqs createtsv metagenome1_DB metagenome1_mmseqs_taxonomy.txt metagenome1_mmseqs_taxonomy_final.txt
```

The split-memory-limit flag sped up the process and the final line put all the split files back together

Comment: Thanks @Rainman